# Is it possible to get specific value from deeply nested JSON string?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to get specific value from deeply nested stringified JSON.

Below is the example

```
const arr = [
    {
        "type": "exception-handler",
        "action": "try-catch",
        "extra": {
            "id": "aefwwefefwARG@.[t.2"
        },
        "try": [
            {
                "type": "unit",
                "action": "create",
                "request": [
                    {
                        "type": "operator",
                        "action": "request",
                        "extra": {
                            "id": "%m6nwefewfqAuo!@"
                        },
                        "id": "58282ac47ccc45b79c6bc",
                        "method": {
                            "type": "miscellaneous",
                            "action": "protocol-method",
                            "extra": {
                                "id": "H+JewwefeTgHv"
                            },
                            "method": "post"
                        },
                        "end-point": {
                            "type": "protocol-end-point",
                            "action": "url",
                            "extra": {
                                "id": "=wefwefqe"
                            },
                            "end-point": {
                                "type": "primitive",
                                "action": "string",
                                "extra": {
                                    "id": "wefwefewfewd!"
                                },
                                "value": "http://localhost:8081/plan/entrance"
                            }
                        },
                        "header": {
                            "type": "hashmap",
                            "action": "create",
                            "extra": {
                                "id": "[wvsdvsdvsdvY"
                            },
                            "values": [
                                {
                                    "type": "parameter",
                                    "action": "create",
                                    "extra": {
                                        "id": "sdfwefwef"
                                    },
                                    "key": {
                                        "type": "primitive",
                                        "action": "string",
                                        "extra": {
                                            "id": "sdfvwvwv_-|z*"
                                        },
                                        "value": "Content-Type"
                                    },
                                    "value": {
                                        "type": "miscellaneous",
                                        "action": "protocol-content-type",
                                        "content-type": "application/json"
                                    },
                                    "description": {
                                        "type": "primitive",
                                        "action": "string",
                                        "extra": {
                                            "id": "4xW$1)uu^o5Qyd*:_%b-"
                                        },
                                        "value": "Content-Type"
                                    },
                                    "datatype": {
                                        "type": "miscellaneous",
                                        "action": "parameter-type",
                                        "extra": {
                                            "id": "0q;~b_SF4bUu|y`I~5@W"
                                        },
                                        "parameter-type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "required": {
                                        "type": "primitive",
                                        "action": "boolean",
                                        "extra": {
                                            "id": "pddddvwvewerr"
                                        },
                                        "value": true
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "body": {
                            "type": "hashmap",
                            "action": "create",
                            "extra": {
                                "id": "wecwcecweqweq"
                            },
                            "values": []
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "response": [
                    {
                        "type": "operator",
                        "action": "response",
                        "extra": {
                            "id": "u^ewfvwKlbu"
                        },
                        "id": "d2a26b2943c12fc9c493cb152773c1ad",
                        "context": [
                            {
                                "type": "response-context",
                                "action": "create",
                                "extra": {
                                    "id": "/wfefwf]JbM"
                                },
                                "status_code": {
                                    "type": "primitive",
                                    "action": "integer",
                                    "extra": {
                                        "id": "bYhweqwdqwVZs:~"
                                    },
                                    "value": 200
                                },
                                "header": {
                                    "type": "hashmap",
                                    "action": "create",
                                    "extra": {
                                        "id": "$0{7z~p%Yp.{`SMtV!o#"
                                    },
                                    "values": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "parameter",
                                            "action": "create",
                                            "extra": {
                                                "id": "efwefwB"
                                            },
                                            "key": {
                                                "type": "primitive",
                                                "action": "string",
                                                "extra": {
                                                    "id": "#9.Rwefvwvfs"
                                                },
                                                "value": "Content-Type"
                                            },
                                            "value": {
                                                "type": "miscellaneous",
                                                "action": "protocol-content-type",
                                                "content-type": "application/json"
                                            },
                                            "description": {
                                                "type": "primitive",
                                                "action": "strwffwe",
                                                "extra": {
                                                    "id": "I=jUZ6Xc-u}UfqHqe8T6"
                                                },
                                                "value": "Content-Type"
                                            },
                                            "datatype": {
                                                "type": "miscellaneous",
                                                "action": "parameter-type",
                                                "extra": {
                                                    "id": "B*(qy~(zjjjI-,u*aN-."
                                                },
                                                "parameter-type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "required": {
                                                "type": "primitive",
                                                "action": "boolean",
                                                "extra": {
                                                    "id": "!_4.P~5A#DR(.@j#tee_"
                                                },
                                                "value": true
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "body": {
                                    "type": "hashmap",
                                    "action": "create",
                                    "extra": {
                                        "id": "2xlF!I@063F+ag4%AGGn"
                                    },
                                    "values": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "parameter",
                                            "action": "create",
                                            "extra": {
                                                "id": "QNc=;UPk5m`g?d+p$F;)"
                                            },
                                            "key": {
                                                "type": "primitive",
                                                "action": "string",
                                                "extra": {
                                                    "id": "fX7,hQW_SvG-HI_Kbvc,"
                                                },
                                                "value": "result"
                                            },
                                            "value": {
                                                "type": "variable",
                                                "action": "get",
                                                "extra": {
                                                    "id": "_41Rlcb++on)q=sb,i$e"
                                                },
                                                "name": {
                                                    "type": "primitive",
                                                    "action": "string",
                                                    "extra": {
                                                        "id": "31AhsBljlkYm=9aLy+Wt"
                                                    },
                                                    "value": "qqq1"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "description": {
                                                "type": "primitive",
                                                "action": "string",
                                                "extra": {
                                                    "id": "Si$=Ebxj{Yyt2yI;s@:e"
                                                },
                                                "value": "result"
                                            },
                                            "datatype": {
                                                "type": "miscellaneous",
                                                "action": "parameter-type",
                                                "extra": {
                                                    "id": "L3Z?PB8k6)D]5##_U*63"
                                                },
                                                "parameter-type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "required": {
                                                "type": "primitive",
                                                "action": "boolean",
                                                "extra": {
                                                    "id": "=3QlBlyN%72a#E{!4ovC"
                                                },
                                                "value": false
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "statements": [
                    {
                        "type": "helper",
                        "action": "code-section",
                        "extra": {
                            "id": ")$x]%MY;vXFM66t$[#3g"
                        },
                        "statements": [
                            {
                                "type": "document",
                                "action": "comment-note",
                                "extra": {
                                    "id": "8prbh]Hq?^s2BV=`J4|$"
                                },
                                "comment": {
                                    "type": "primitive",
                                    "action": "string",
                                    "value": "code 1"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "variable",
                                "action": "create",
                                "extra": {
                                    "id": "QubE)kG{r7H9xR-}CHF7"
                                },
                                "name": {
                                    "type": "primitive",
                                    "action": "string",
                                    "extra": {
                                        "id": "h=rET1COg7/YoxR{OfYz"
                                    },
                                    "value": "qqq2"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "variable",
                                "action": "set",
                                "extra": {
                                    "id": "p[gSm|F$@CU3M_F!Tl!o"
                                },
                                "name": {
                                    "type": "primitive",
                                    "action": "string",
                                    "extra": {
                                        "id": "Y9)#ccnXbtpN}[zq!U!a"
                                    },
                                    "value": "qqq2"
                                },
                                "value": {
                                    "type": "pair",
                                    "action": "create",
                                    "extra": {
                                        "id": "b=/HL|O--7^=~{c4]SYk"
                                    },
                                    "key": {
                                        "type": "primitive",
                                        "action": "string",
                                        "extra": {
                                            "id": "2,aMj@kiv$aG]2Fg(X+F"
                                        },
                                        "value": "qqq"
                                    },
                                    "value": {
                                        "type": "pair",
                                        "action": "create",
                                        "extra": {
                                            "id": "_]kqE^cuy#mK!s5~KufR"
                                        },
                                        "key": {
                                            "type": "primitive",
                                            "action": "string",
                                            "extra": {
                                                "id": "u9v[T7T4t]oRB)KMKAo7"
                                            },
                                            "value": "qqq"
                                        },
                                        "value": {
                                            "type": "primitive",
                                            "action": "string",
                                            "extra": {
                                                "id": "/,V=$)=-Ex*1KAQpKim7"
                                            },
                                            "value": "1234"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "helper",
                        "action": "code-section",
                        "extra": {
                            "id": "Nwefwvwwe|T;2"
                        },
                        "statements": [
                            {
                                "type": "document",
                                "action": "comment-note",
                                "extra": {
                                    "id": "!hba3~wcwe+!AjcF"
                                },
                                "comment": {
                                    "type": "primitive",
                                    "action": "string",
                                    "value": "code 2"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "variable",
                                "action": "create",
                                "extra": {
                                    "id": "`.zqkDw?Qd$BD#;U`pb7"
                                },
                                "name": {
                                    "type": "primitive",
                                    "action": "string",
                                    "extra": {
                                        "id": "awefwvevK~0Y"
                                    },
                                    "value": "qqq1"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "variable",
                                "action": "set",
                                "extra": {
                                    "id": "S,wVwvvefdwefFx/"
                                },
                                "name": {
                                    "type": "primitive",
                                    "action": "string",
                                    "extra": {
                                        "id": ":QwevdsdvdWex"
                                    },
                                    "value": "qqq1"
                                },
                                "value": {
                                    "type": "custom-util",
                                    "action": "create",
                                    "extra": {
                                        "id": "xLwedwvwev|K"
                                    },
                                    "arguments": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "pair",
                                            "action": "create",
                                            "extra": {
                                                "id": "ig-vsdvsdO0O80D!"
                                            },
                                            "key": {
                                                "type": "primitive",
                                                "action": "string",
                                                "extra": {
                                                    "id": "AJOawef`hZ|d,"
                                                },
                                                "value": "arg1"
                                            },
                                            "value": {
                                                "type": "primitive",
                                                "action": "null",
                                                "extra": {
                                                    "id": "8MraKndfsdf;$MF4Cb"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "type": "pair",
                                            "action": "create",
                                            "extra": {
                                                "id": "`eeGi4|7oGaRT7UB;AvP"
                                            },
                                            "key": {
                                                "type": "primitive",
                                                "action": "string",
                                                "extra": {
                                                    "id": "vewdqwd4X"
                                                },
                                                "value": "arg2"
                                            },
                                            "value": {
                                                "type": "primitive",
                                                "action": "null",
                                                "extra": {
                                                    "id": "Xcswefsddv,"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "payload": [],
                                    "return-value": {
                                        "type": "primitive",
                                        "action": "string",
                                        "extra": {
                                            "id": "eodx(7Oz7)7Gw;.dF4kt"
                                        },
                                        "value": "retData"
                                    },
                                    "property": {
                                        "type": "property",
                                        "action": "custom-util",
                                        "extra": [],
                                        "id": {
                                            "type": "primitive",
                                            "action": "string",
                                            "extra": [],
                                            "value": "3e1589wewefewfq2332cc2a83"
                                        },
                                        "name": {
                                            "type": "primitive",
                                            "action": "string",
                                            "extra": [],
                                            "value": "test1"
                                        },
                                        "description": {
                                            "type": "primitive",
                                            "action": "string",
                                            "extra": [],
                                            "value": ""
                                        },
                                        "created-date": {
                                            "type": "primitive",
                                            "action": "string",
                                            "extra": [],
                                            "value": ""
                                        },
                                        "updated-date": {
                                            "type": "primitive",
                                            "action": "string",
                                            "extra": [],
                                            "value": ""
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "catchers": [
            {
                "type": "exception-handler",
                "action": "exception-catcher",
                "extra": {
                    "id": "6ZCfwefwfewfO)f}UF!"
                },
                "id": "064673gerg081c4e1",
                "exceptions": [
                    {
                        "type": "miscellaneous",
                        "action": "exception-type",
                        "extra": {
                            "id": "IQRLF7Shgd46:T!UXA~V"
                        },
                        "exception-type": "RuntimeException"
                    }
                ],
                "statements": []
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

This is deeply nested array with object and it could be nested deeper. And I want to get string `id`s inside `extra` object.

```
"extra": {
   "id": "aefwwefefwARG@.[t.2"
 },
```

And make them as a set of array like below.

```
const ids = ["aefwwefefwARG@.[t.2", "%m6nwefewfqAuo!@", "H+JewwefeTgHv", ...]
```

I used JSON.stringify method to flatten the array. However, I forgot when I use the method, the array is converted to a string. Therefore I am not able to get the specific object with key name `extra`.

Is there way I can get the value of `extra` from stringified array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't need to JSON.stringify.
If your json structure is in an object `json`.
You can try something like:

```js
function findKeyValuesInJson(json, needle_key, nested_needle) {
   let found_values = [];
   let objectsToCheck = [json];
   while(objectsToCheck.length > 0) {
      let obj = objectsToCheck.pop();
      let keysToCheck = Object.keys(obj);
      while(keysToCheck.length > 0) {
         let key = keysToCheck.pop();
         if (key === needle_key) {
            found_values.push(obj[key])
            if(nested_needle && typeof obj[key] === 'object' && obj[key] !== null) {
               objectsToCheck.push(obj[key]);
            }
         } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && obj[key] !== null) {
            objectsToCheck.push(obj[key]);
         }
      }
   }
   return found_values;
}
function findExtraInJson(json) {
   return findKeyValuesInJson(json, 'extra');
}
const extraProps = findExtraInJson(json);
```

It basically iterates through the entire object and collects the
values of key `extra` in an array.

By default, we're not checking the key `extra` again for the key `extra`. You can enable that by passing `true` as the third argument to `findKeyValuesInJson` or you can put the if statement with `objectsToCheck(obj[key])` outside the else-if statement so that all keys will go through with this check.

After getting the property values in an array, you can filter/map it and get what you need like this:

```js
extraProps
    .filter(extra => extra.id !== undefined)
    .map(extra => extra.id);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another approach recursively visiting an array passed as input and returning an array of values of all the `.extra.id` property values found in its nested objects.

As a side note, please forget what you think to know about json. That's a formal syntax to serialize javascript objects. You actually have a javascript object definition there and that's all we need here. `JSON.stringify` would be needed to serialize the object but it's not our approach here.

This is the main logics:

```
//visits the arr array recursively looking for objects having .extra.id
//that, if found, will be pushed in the accumulator
function grabExtraIds(arr, accumulator = []) {
  //for each item in the array
  arr.forEach(nestedObject => {

    //pushes the .extra.id value of this nestedObject if existent
    const extraId = nestedObject ? .extra ? .id;
    if (extraId !== undefined)
      accumulator.push(extraId);

    //for each property of the current nestedObject
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(nestedObject)
      .forEach(propertyName => {
        const property = nestedObject[propertyName];
        //if the property value is of type array
        if (Array.isArray(property))
          //recursively call the grabExtraIds with this object
          grabExtraIds(property, accumulator);
      });
  });
}
```

This is the found ids:

```
[
  "aefwwefefwARG@.[t.2",
  "%m6nwefewfqAuo!@",
  "u^ewfvwKlbu",
  "/wfefwf]JbM",
  ")$x]%MY;vXFM66t$[#3g",
  "8prbh]Hq?^s2BV=`J4|$",
  "QubE)kG{r7H9xR-}CHF7",
  "p[gSm|F$@CU3M_F!Tl!o",
  "Nwefwvwwe|T;2",
  "!hba3~wcwe+!AjcF",
  "`.zqkDw?Qd$BD#;U`pb7",
  "S,wVwvvefdwefFx/",
  "6ZCfwefwfewfO)f}UF!",
  "IQRLF7Shgd46:T!UXA~V"
]
```

And this is the live demo:

```js
const arr = [{
  "type": "exception-handler",
  "action": "try-catch",
  "extra": {
    "id": "aefwwefefwARG@.[t.2"
  },
  "try": [{
    "type": "unit",
    "action": "create",
    "request": [{
      "type": "operator",
      "action": "request",
      "extra": {
        "id": "%m6nwefewfqAuo!@"
      },
      "id": "58282ac47ccc45b79c6bc",
      "method": {
        "type": "miscellaneous",
        "action": "protocol-method",
        "extra": {
          "id": "H+JewwefeTgHv"
        },
        "method": "post"
      },
      "end-point": {
        "type": "protocol-end-point",
        "action": "url",
        "extra": {
          "id": "=wefwefqe"
        },
        "end-point": {
          "type": "primitive",
          "action": "string",
          "extra": {
            "id": "wefwefewfewd!"
          },
          "value": "http://localhost:8081/plan/entrance"
        }
      },
      "header": {
        "type": "hashmap",
        "action": "create",
        "extra": {
          "id": "[wvsdvsdvsdvY"
        },
        "values": [{
          "type": "parameter",
          "action": "create",
          "extra": {
            "id": "sdfwefwef"
          },
          "key": {
            "type": "primitive",
            "action": "string",
            "extra": {
              "id": "sdfvwvwv_-|z*"
            },
            "value": "Content-Type"
          },
          "value": {
            "type": "miscellaneous",
            "action": "protocol-content-type",
            "content-type": "application/json"
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "primitive",
            "action": "string",
            "extra": {
              "id": "4xW$1)uu^o5Qyd*:_%b-"
            },
            "value": "Content-Type"
          },
          "datatype": {
            "type": "miscellaneous",
            "action": "parameter-type",
            "extra": {
              "id": "0q;~b_SF4bUu|y`I~5@W"
            },
            "parameter-type": "string"
          },
          "required": {
            "type": "primitive",
            "action": "boolean",
            "extra": {
              "id": "pddddvwvewerr"
            },
            "value": true
          }
        }]
      },
      "body": {
        "type": "hashmap",
        "action": "create",
        "extra": {
          "id": "wecwcecweqweq"
        },
        "values": []
      }
    }],
    "response": [{
      "type": "operator",
      "action": "response",
      "extra": {
        "id": "u^ewfvwKlbu"
      },
      "id": "d2a26b2943c12fc9c493cb152773c1ad",
      "context": [{
        "type": "response-context",
        "action": "create",
        "extra": {
          "id": "/wfefwf]JbM"
        },
        "status_code": {
          "type": "primitive",
          "action": "integer",
          "extra": {
            "id": "bYhweqwdqwVZs:~"
          },
          "value": 200
        },
        "header": {
          "type": "hashmap",
          "action": "create",
          "extra": {
            "id": "$0{7z~p%Yp.{`SMtV!o#"
          },
          "values": [{
            "type": "parameter",
            "action": "create",
            "extra": {
              "id": "efwefwB"
            },
            "key": {
              "type": "primitive",
              "action": "string",
              "extra": {
                "id": "#9.Rwefvwvfs"
              },
              "value": "Content-Type"
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "miscellaneous",
              "action": "protocol-content-type",
              "content-type": "application/json"
            },
            "description": {
              "type": "primitive",
              "action": "strwffwe",
              "extra": {
                "id": "I=jUZ6Xc-u}UfqHqe8T6"
              },
              "value": "Content-Type"
            },
            "datatype": {
              "type": "miscellaneous",
              "action": "parameter-type",
              "extra": {
                "id": "B*(qy~(zjjjI-,u*aN-."
              },
              "parameter-type": "string"
            },
            "required": {
              "type": "primitive",
              "action": "boolean",
              "extra": {
                "id": "!_4.P~5A#DR(.@j#tee_"
              },
              "value": true
            }
          }]
        },
        "body": {
          "type": "hashmap",
          "action": "create",
          "extra": {
            "id": "2xlF!I@063F+ag4%AGGn"
          },
          "values": [{
            "type": "parameter",
            "action": "create",
            "extra": {
              "id": "QNc=;UPk5m`g?d+p$F;)"
            },
            "key": {
              "type": "primitive",
              "action": "string",
              "extra": {
                "id": "fX7,hQW_SvG-HI_Kbvc,"
              },
              "value": "result"
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "variable",
              "action": "get",
              "extra": {
                "id": "_41Rlcb++on)q=sb,i$e"
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "primitive",
                "action": "string",
                "extra": {
                  "id": "31AhsBljlkYm=9aLy+Wt"
                },
                "value": "qqq1"
              }
            },
            "description": {
              "type": "primitive",
              "action": "string",
              "extra": {
                "id": "Si$=Ebxj{Yyt2yI;s@:e"
              },
              "value": "result"
            },
            "datatype": {
              "type": "miscellaneous",
              "action": "parameter-type",
              "extra": {
                "id": "L3Z?PB8k6)D]5##_U*63"
              },
              "parameter-type": "string"
            },
            "required": {
              "type": "primitive",
              "action": "boolean",
              "extra": {
                "id": "=3QlBlyN%72a#E{!4ovC"
              },
              "value": false
            }
          }]
        }
      }]
    }],
    "statements": [{
        "type": "helper",
        "action": "code-section",
        "extra": {
          "id": ")$x]%MY;vXFM66t$[#3g"
        },
        "statements": [{
            "type": "document",
            "action": "comment-note",
            "extra": {
              "id": "8prbh]Hq?^s2BV=`J4|$"
            },
            "comment": {
              "type": "primitive",
              "action": "string",
              "value": "code 1"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "variable",
            "action": "create",
            "extra": {
              "id": "QubE)kG{r7H9xR-}CHF7"
            },
            "name": {
              "type": "primitive",
              "action": "string",
              "extra": {
                "id": "h=rET1COg7/YoxR{OfYz"
              },
              "value": "qqq2"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "variable",
            "action": "set",
            "extra": {
              "id": "p[gSm|F$@CU3M_F!Tl!o"
            },
            "name": {
              "type": "primitive",
              "action": "string",
              "extra": {
                "id": "Y9)#ccnXbtpN}[zq!U!a"
              },
              "value": "qqq2"
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "pair",
              "action": "create",
              "extra": {
                "id": "b=/HL|O--7^=~{c4]SYk"
              },
              "key": {
                "type": "primitive",
                "action": "string",
                "extra": {
                  "id": "2,aMj@kiv$aG]2Fg(X+F"
                },
                "value": "qqq"
              },
              "value": {
                "type": "pair",
                "action": "create",
                "extra": {
                  "id": "_]kqE^cuy#mK!s5~KufR"
                },
                "key": {
                  "type": "primitive",
                  "action": "string",
                  "extra": {
                    "id": "u9v[T7T4t]oRB)KMKAo7"
                  },
                  "value": "qqq"
                },
                "value": {
                  "type": "primitive",
                  "action": "string",
                  "extra": {
                    "id": "/,V=$)=-Ex*1KAQpKim7"
                  },
                  "value": "1234"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "helper",
        "action": "code-section",
        "extra": {
          "id": "Nwefwvwwe|T;2"
        },
        "statements": [{
            "type": "document",
            "action": "comment-note",
            "extra": {
              "id": "!hba3~wcwe+!AjcF"
            },
            "comment": {
              "type": "primitive",
              "action": "string",
              "value": "code 2"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "variable",
            "action": "create",
            "extra": {
              "id": "`.zqkDw?Qd$BD#;U`pb7"
            },
            "name": {
              "type": "primitive",
              "action": "string",
              "extra": {
                "id": "awefwvevK~0Y"
              },
              "value": "qqq1"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "variable",
            "action": "set",
            "extra": {
              "id": "S,wVwvvefdwefFx/"
            },
            "name": {
              "type": "primitive",
              "action": "string",
              "extra": {
                "id": ":QwevdsdvdWex"
              },
              "value": "qqq1"
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "custom-util",
              "action": "create",
              "extra": {
                "id": "xLwedwvwev|K"
              },
              "arguments": [{
                  "type": "pair",
                  "action": "create",
                  "extra": {
                    "id": "ig-vsdvsdO0O80D!"
                  },
                  "key": {
                    "type": "primitive",
                    "action": "string",
                    "extra": {
                      "id": "AJOawef`hZ|d,"
                    },
                    "value": "arg1"
                  },
                  "value": {
                    "type": "primitive",
                    "action": "null",
                    "extra": {
                      "id": "8MraKndfsdf;$MF4Cb"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "type": "pair",
                  "action": "create",
                  "extra": {
                    "id": "`eeGi4|7oGaRT7UB;AvP"
                  },
                  "key": {
                    "type": "primitive",
                    "action": "string",
                    "extra": {
                      "id": "vewdqwd4X"
                    },
                    "value": "arg2"
                  },
                  "value": {
                    "type": "primitive",
                    "action": "null",
                    "extra": {
                      "id": "Xcswefsddv,"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ],
              "payload": [],
              "return-value": {
                "type": "primitive",
                "action": "string",
                "extra": {
                  "id": "eodx(7Oz7)7Gw;.dF4kt"
                },
                "value": "retData"
              },
              "property": {
                "type": "property",
                "action": "custom-util",
                "extra": [],
                "id": {
                  "type": "primitive",
                  "action": "string",
                  "extra": [],
                  "value": "3e1589wewefewfq2332cc2a83"
                },
                "name": {
                  "type": "primitive",
                  "action": "string",
                  "extra": [],
                  "value": "test1"
                },
                "description": {
                  "type": "primitive",
                  "action": "string",
                  "extra": [],
                  "value": ""
                },
                "created-date": {
                  "type": "primitive",
                  "action": "string",
                  "extra": [],
                  "value": ""
                },
                "updated-date": {
                  "type": "primitive",
                  "action": "string",
                  "extra": [],
                  "value": ""
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }],
  "catchers": [{
    "type": "exception-handler",
    "action": "exception-catcher",
    "extra": {
      "id": "6ZCfwefwfewfO)f}UF!"
    },
    "id": "064673gerg081c4e1",
    "exceptions": [{
      "type": "miscellaneous",
      "action": "exception-type",
      "extra": {
        "id": "IQRLF7Shgd46:T!UXA~V"
      },
      "exception-type": "RuntimeException"
    }],
    "statements": []
  }]
}];

//visits the arr array recursively looking for objects having .extra.id that will be pushed in the accumulator
function grabExtraIds(arr, accumulator = []){      
  //for each item in the array
  arr.forEach(nestedObject => {
  
    //pushes the .extra.id value of this nestedObject if existent
    const extraId = nestedObject?.extra?.id;
    if(extraId !== undefined)
      accumulator.push( extraId );    
    
    //for each property of the current nestedObject
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(nestedObject)
      .forEach( propertyName =>{            
        const property = nestedObject[propertyName];
        //if the property value is of type array
        if (Array.isArray(property))
          //recursively call the grabExtraIds with this object
          grabExtraIds(property, accumulator);      
      });  
    });
}

const result = [];
grabExtraIds(arr, result);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This found 16 ids. the id inside of extra object should be 56 ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a recursive function, let's call it `getAllPropertyValues()`.

We loop over each key in the input object `obj`, if the value at that key is an object (or array) we call getAllPropertyValues on the value, if not we'll add the value to the result array *if* it matches the desired property.

You could use a Set() if you wished to get only unique ids rather than each and every one.

We'll match only the desired `extra` objects by passing in a `parent` value and testing against each object's parent.

```js
const arr = [ { "type": "exception-handler", "action": "try-catch", "extra": { "id": "aefwwefefwARG@.[t.2" }, "try": [ { "type": "unit", "action": "create", "request": [ { "type": "operator", "action": "request", "extra": { "id": "%m6nwefewfqAuo!@" }, "id": "58282ac47ccc45b79c6bc", "method": { "type": "miscellaneous", "action": "protocol-method", "extra": { "id": "H+JewwefeTgHv" }, "method": "post" }, "end-point": { "type": "protocol-end-point", "action": "url", "extra": { "id": "=wefwefqe" }, "end-point": { "type": "primitive", "action": "string", "extra": { "id": "wefwefewfewd!" }, "value": "http://localhost:8081/plan/entrance" } }, "header": { "type": "hashmap", "action": "create", "extra": { "id": "[wvsdvsdvsdvY" }, "values": [ { "type": "parameter", "action": "create", "extra": { "id": "sdfwefwef" }, "key": { "type": "primitive", "action": "string", "extra": { "id": "sdfvwvwv_-|z*" }, "value": "Content-Type" }, "value": { "type": "miscellaneous", "action": "protocol-content-type", "content-type": "application/json" }, "description": { "type": "primitive", "action": "string", "extra": { "id": "4xW$1)uu^o5Qyd*:_%b-" }, "value": "Content-Type" }, "datatype": { "type": "miscellaneous", "action": "parameter-type", "extra": { "id": "0q;~b_SF4bUu|y`I~5@W" }, "parameter-type": "string" }, "required": { "type": "primitive", "action": "boolean", "extra": { "id": "pddddvwvewerr" }, "value": true } } ] }, "body": { "type": "hashmap", "action": "create", "extra": { "id": "wecwcecweqweq" }, "values": [] } } ], "response": [ { "type": "operator", "action": "response", "extra": { "id": "u^ewfvwKlbu" }, "id": "d2a26b2943c12fc9c493cb152773c1ad", "context": [ { "type": "response-context", "action": "create", "extra": { "id": "/wfefwf]JbM" }, "status_code": { "type": "primitive", "action": "integer", "extra": { "id": "bYhweqwdqwVZs:~" }, "value": 200 }, "header": { "type": "hashmap", "action": "create", "extra": { "id": "$0{7z~p%Yp.{`SMtV!o#" }, "values": [ { "type": "parameter", "action": "create", "extra": { "id": "efwefwB" }, "key": { "type": "primitive", "action": "string", "extra": { "id": "#9.Rwefvwvfs" }, "value": "Content-Type" }, "value": { "type": "miscellaneous", "action": "protocol-content-type", "content-type": "application/json" }, "description": { "type": "primitive", "action": "strwffwe", "extra": { "id": "I=jUZ6Xc-u}UfqHqe8T6" }, "value": "Content-Type" }, "datatype": { "type": "miscellaneous", "action": "parameter-type", "extra": { "id": "B*(qy~(zjjjI-,u*aN-." }, "parameter-type": "string" }, "required": { "type": "primitive", "action": "boolean", "extra": { "id": "!_4.P~5A#DR(.@j#tee_" }, "value": true } } ] }, "body": { "type": "hashmap", "action": "create", "extra": { "id": "2xlF!I@063F+ag4%AGGn" }, "values": [ { "type": "parameter", "action": "create", "extra": { "id": "QNc=;UPk5m`g?d+p$F;)" }, "key": { "type": "primitive", "action": "string", "extra": { "id": "fX7,hQW_SvG-HI_Kbvc," }, "value": "result" }, "value": { "type": "variable", "action": "get", "extra": { "id": "_41Rlcb++on)q=sb,i$e" }, "name": { "type": "primitive", "action": "string", "extra": { "id": "31AhsBljlkYm=9aLy+Wt" }, "value": "qqq1" } }, "description": { "type": "primitive", "action": "string", "extra": { "id": "Si$=Ebxj{Yyt2yI;s@:e" }, "value": "result" }, "datatype": { "type": "miscellaneous", "action": "parameter-type", "extra": { "id": "L3Z?PB8k6)D]5##_U*63" }, "parameter-type": "string" }, "required": { "type": "primitive", "action": "boolean", "extra": { "id": "=3QlBlyN%72a#E{!4ovC" }, "value": false } } ] } } ] } ], "statements": [ { "type": "helper", "action": "code-section", "extra": { "id": ")$x]%MY;vXFM66t$[#3g" }, "statements": [ { "type": "document", "action": "comment-note", "extra": { "id": "8prbh]Hq?^s2BV=`J4|$" }, "comment": { "type": "primitive", "action": "string", "value": "code 1" } }, { "type": "variable", "action": "create", "extra": { "id": "QubE)kG{r7H9xR-}CHF7" }, "name": { "type": "primitive", "action": "string", "extra": { "id": "h=rET1COg7/YoxR{OfYz" }, "value": "qqq2" } }, { "type": "variable", "action": "set", "extra": { "id": "p[gSm|F$@CU3M_F!Tl!o" }, "name": { "type": "primitive", "action": "string", "extra": { "id": "Y9)#ccnXbtpN}[zq!U!a" }, "value": "qqq2" }, "value": { "type": "pair", "action": "create", "extra": { "id": "b=/HL|O--7^=~{c4]SYk" }, "key": { "type": "primitive", "action": "string", "extra": { "id": "2,aMj@kiv$aG]2Fg(X+F" }, "value": "qqq" }, "value": { "type": "pair", "action": "create", "extra": { "id": "_]kqE^cuy#mK!s5~KufR" }, "key": { "type": "primitive", "action": "string", "extra": { "id": "u9v[T7T4t]oRB)KMKAo7" }, "value": "qqq" }, "value": { "type": "primitive", "action": "string", "extra": { "id": "/,V=$)=-Ex*1KAQpKim7" }, "value": "1234" } } } } ] }, { "type": "helper", "action": "code-section", "extra": { "id": "Nwefwvwwe|T;2" }, "statements": [ { "type": "document", "action": "comment-note", "extra": { "id": "!hba3~wcwe+!AjcF" }, "comment": { "type": "primitive", "action": "string", "value": "code 2" } }, { "type": "variable", "action": "create", "extra": { "id": "`.zqkDw?Qd$BD#;U`pb7" }, "name": { "type": "primitive", "action": "string", "extra": { "id": "awefwvevK~0Y" }, "value": "qqq1" } }, { "type": "variable", "action": "set", "extra": { "id": "S,wVwvvefdwefFx/" }, "name": { "type": "primitive", "action": "string", "extra": { "id": ":QwevdsdvdWex" }, "value": "qqq1" }, "value": { "type": "custom-util", "action": "create", "extra": { "id": "xLwedwvwev|K" }, "arguments": [ { "type": "pair", "action": "create", "extra": { "id": "ig-vsdvsdO0O80D!" }, "key": { "type": "primitive", "action": "string", "extra": { "id": "AJOawef`hZ|d," }, "value": "arg1" }, "value": { "type": "primitive", "action": "null", "extra": { "id": "8MraKndfsdf;$MF4Cb" } } }, { "type": "pair", "action": "create", "extra": { "id": "`eeGi4|7oGaRT7UB;AvP" }, "key": { "type": "primitive", "action": "string", "extra": { "id": "vewdqwd4X" }, "value": "arg2" }, "value": { "type": "primitive", "action": "null", "extra": { "id": "Xcswefsddv," } } } ], "payload": [], "return-value": { "type": "primitive", "action": "string", "extra": { "id": "eodx(7Oz7)7Gw;.dF4kt" }, "value": "retData" }, "property": { "type": "property", "action": "custom-util", "extra": [], "id": { "type": "primitive", "action": "string", "extra": [], "value": "3e1589wewefewfq2332cc2a83" }, "name": { "type": "primitive", "action": "string", "extra": [], "value": "test1" }, "description": { "type": "primitive", "action": "string", "extra": [], "value": "" }, "created-date": { "type": "primitive", "action": "string", "extra": [], "value": "" }, "updated-date": { "type": "primitive", "action": "string", "extra": [], "value": "" } } } } ] } ] } ], "catchers": [ { "type": "exception-handler", "action": "exception-catcher", "extra": { "id": "6ZCfwefwfewfO)f}UF!" }, "id": "064673gerg081c4e1", "exceptions": [ { "type": "miscellaneous", "action": "exception-type", "extra": { "id": "IQRLF7Shgd46:T!UXA~V" }, "exception-type": "RuntimeException" } ], "statements": [] } ] } ];

function getAllPropertyValues(obj, property, parent, parentKey = '') {
    let values = [];
    for(let k in obj) {
        if (obj[k] && typeof(obj[k]) === 'object') {
            values = [...values, ...getAllPropertyValues(obj[k], property, parent, k)]
        } else if ((k === property) && (parent === parentKey)) { 
            values.push(obj[k])
        }
    }
    return values;
}

console.log('Id array:', getAllPropertyValues(arr, 'id', 'extra'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: This doesn't work properly, there are some "id" property that doesn't belong in "extra" object. like in the object "catchers" there are "extra id: 6ZCfwefwfewfO)f}UF!" and a "normal id: 064673gerg081c4e1"

Comment: is for in expression is for the object literal not the array?

Comment: It will work for either, you can use for .. in in objects and also for arrays. Normally you'd iterate over arrays with for .. of though!